# Is it possible to crease a NURBS vertex?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am learning how to make vector like graphics using a NURBS curve, and it looks like a very powerful method, except I can not find a way to 'crease' a vertex. The vertices are automatically smoothed, and my result looks like this:

[image: Quill example]

I want to be able to make the circled areas sharper, while keeping all other parts the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) is a complected and complex subject. I feel that for general modeling a bézier is preferable.

This quote from [the old blender docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Curves) gives a hint as to the differences between NURBS and bézier curves.

> For example a Bézier circle is a polynomial approximation of a circle, and this approximation is noticeable, whereas a NURBS circle is exactly a circle. However, a NURBS cannot have real sharp angles in it, unlike a Bézier curve…
>
> NURBS curves require a little bit more understanding of the underlying components that make up a NURBS curve in order to get full use of them. They have a large set of variables, which allow you to create mathematically pure forms. However, working with them requires a little more discussion on the various parts of a NURBS curve.

NURBS objects can not easily easily represent a sharp corner. There are only two ways to "crease" a NURBS.

First there is the *Weight* setting for each control point. This setting found in the properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) it controls how much force each point has on the NURBS.
[image: weight setting]
It you look at the NurbsCircle object, the control points in the corners (highleted in red) all have a weight of *0.353553* while the four in the middle have a weight of *1*. However, if you were to set all the control points to 1 you would **not** have a square.
[image: NurbsCircle object]

Second there is the *[Order](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Order)* setting in the *Active Spline* section of the *Curve* tab of the Properties panel. The order setting controls how big of a area the control points have. Smaller numbers equal sharper corners, because fewer points are mathematically controlling the placement of the NURBS.  [image: Active Spline settings]

Answer (score 6):

In your example a bezier curve will make it easier to get 'sharp' points in your curve as the control handles for each point give more control over how the curve enters and leaves each point.

If you do need to use nurbs and also need a 'sharp' point you can place three points close together which reduces the smooth interpolation between points to what visually appears to be a point.

[image]

In edit mode if you zoom right in you can see -

[image]